# EF Core Generic Repository get Id from new inserted generic entity async

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

**Goal**: get id of the inserted generic entity by using async with ASP.NET Core

**Problem**: what part am I missing in order to achieve the goal?

Code:

```
public async Task<int> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddAsync)} entity must not be null");
    }

    try
    {
        await _context.AddAsync(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return <Id Here>   
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be saved");
    }
}
```

Thank you!

---

[image]

It doesn't work to use id.

---

It doesnt work to use where T.

[image]

Comment: Does `return entity.Id` work?

Comment: .id doesnt work. Please take a look at the picture

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface with Id property and have all your entities implement them.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And add a where clause to the generic class.

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public async Task<int> AddAsync(T entity) 
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddAsync)} entity must not be null");
        }

        try
        {
            await _context.AddAsync(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entity.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not 
be saved");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @What'sUP should be `AddAsync<T>` look at documentation
[GenericMethods](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

Comment: I thought your method was generic, you probably have a generic class which need the where clause.

Comment: @What'sUP Please look at the doc i linked, it will help you and first do some own research before ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using reflection:

`return (int)entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entity, null);`

Assuming the naming is `Id` for every table. Otherwise, maybe you can pass the name of the prop as a parameter:

```
public async Task<int> AddAsync<T>(T entity, string paramName) where T : class
{
    // ...
    return (int)entity.GetType().GetProperty(paramName).GetValue(entity, null);
}
```